# How to change the eshell path on Windows

Tags: eshell

When I open `M-x eshell`, and type things I recently added to path I get:
`node: command not found`
where node is the command that has been recently added.
I've added the path to PATH on both the system and user side, I've restarted my computer, and I still get the `command not found message`.

When I run `env`, it returns an old version of the system path.

What do I have to do to update which path `eshell` uses?
I'm using doom emacs if that could be a cause.

Edit: Here's the step-by-step version

```
M-x eshell
$ node -v
node: command not found
```

Seeing this didn't work, I added `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` to both the User and System variable PATH.

I restarted my computer and emacs. The problem persists.

Comment: Show a step-by-step recipe for what you've tried. Say at each step what you see and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: In general, users prefer there to be a global setting within Emacs for the PATH and that usually comes from the variable `process-environment`.  If the O.P. shares that viewpoint, then check the value of the default PATH by using a barebones Emacs without any user settings, aka `emacs -Q`.  This can be done by evaluating `(getenv "PATH")`, which can be done many ways, such as `M-x eval-expression`.  Some users prefer to set the `process-environment` locally and then modify the path on a buffer-local basis.  Eshell sets the *buffer-local* variable `eshell-path-env`, which can be checked:  C-h v

Comment: If `M-x getenv PATH` does not give you the right path then this is a Windows issue. Maybe, it is related to the way you [set the path](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html).